# Coloring strokes in OHLCSeries

Tags: java, jfreechart, candlestick-chart

In candlestick charts is common to draw candles' stroke color (green or red) according to if the stock is rising or falling. Example of standard candlestick chart:

[image]

But in JFreeChart OHLCSeries there is only one option to set the stroke...

```
XYItemRenderer renderer = chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.white);
```

...which is not enough for defining color of rising/falling candle separately.

Example of JFreeChart OHLCSeries:

[image]

**Do you know a way to set a color for rising and falling candles separately?**

Comment: See also [`drawItem`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/CandlestickRenderer.html#line.627).

Comment: @trashgod thanks for comment, please, do you have an example of the method?

Comment: It looks like you'd have to override `drawItem()`.